# Evaluate string variable that contains macro reference

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've got a table with `DataSet` names in, some of which contain macro references in the name.

> e.g. Monthly_Data_&YYMM (where YYMM is the latest month)

I want to keep the `Table` with this string, but then have a new variable with the evaluated `DataSet` name.

> e.g. Monthly_Data_&YYMM,   Monthly_Data_1612

I can't work out a way to do this.  If I read the dataset as a macro variable it returns as the required name, but I can't then join it on the same row as the non evaluated reference.

I'm sure this must be possible, and probably quite easy, but I just can't get my head around how to do this.

Many thanks

Comment: Well, show what you have done here. You have it working, so why don't you show us

Comment: It isn't working here, that's an example of how I want it to work.  The answer below does what I'm after.

Comment: **If I read the dataset as a macro variable it returns as the required name, but I can't then join it on the same row as the non evaluated reference** Means that you have a correct result but not correctly stored into the table... You are the one that write that line, not me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `resolve` function to do this, e.g.

```
%let YYMM = 1601;

data mydata;
  dsname = 'Monthly_Data_&YYMM';
  dsname_resolved = resolve(dsname);
run;
```

N.B. all macro variables used in your column of names must be defined in your session with the correct values at the point when the `resolve` function executes. If two different data sets used the same macro variable in their name, but it took different values at different times, you will need to redefine the macro variable and run your logic separately, possibly via separate data steps or `call symput` + `symget`.